`TypeError` in Stellar SDK and Stellar wallet kit when using `signAndSend` with `signTransaction` implementation inconsistency across devices
I am working on a project that interacts with the Stellar blockchain, using the Stellar SDK and Stellar Wallet Kit to interact with smart contracts. I have a function that is supposed to create a proposal, sign it, and send it using the following code:
Versioning.options.publicKey = publicKey;

const project_key = Buffer.from(
  keccak256.create().update(project_name).digest(),
);

const tx = await Versioning.create_proposal({
  proposer: publicKey,
  project_key: project_key,
  title: title,
  ipfs: ipfs,
  voting_ends_at: BigInt(voting_ends_at),
});

const result = await tx.signAndSend({
  signTransaction: async (xdr) => {
    const { signedTxXdr } = await kit.signTransaction(xdr);
    return signedTxXdr;
  },
});

This code works perfectly fine on my local machine, but when I run it on another PC, it throws the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'switch') at Function.fromXDR (chunk-XKULACZM.js?v=00e7b0e9:15275:23)
at _callee2$ (@stellar stellar-sdk...?v=9e0be720:1617:64) at tryCatch (@stellar stellar-sdk...?v=9e0be720:1206:44)
at Generator.<anonymous> (@stellar stellar-sdk...?v=9e0be720:1283:22) at Generator.next (@stellar stellar-sdk...?v=9e0be720:1229:25)
at asyncGeneratorStep (@stellar stellar-sdk...?v=9e0be720:1446:21) at _next (@stellar stellar-sdk...?v=9e0be720:1458:13)
WriteContractService.ts:228

To troubleshoot, I updated the signAndSend implementation to the following:
const result = await tx.signAndSend({
  signTransaction: async (xdr) => {
    return await kit.signTransaction(xdr);
  },
});

After this change:

The code works fine on the other PC.
However, it now throws a different error on my local machine:

TypeError: envelope.switch is not a function
at Function.fromXDR (chunk-HF7REFZX.js?v=48a2c002:15147:33) at _callee2$ (@stellar stellar-sdk....?v=be451589:1607:64) at tryCatch (@stellar stellar-sdk...?v=be451589:1206:44)
WriteContractService.ts:224

Context:

Both machines are using the same version of the Stellar SDK and Stellar Wallet Kit.
The Stellar Wallet Kit method signTransaction returns the xdr signed transaction, as expected.
The environment appears to be configured similarly on both devices.

Questions:

What could be causing these errors (undefined reading switch and envelope.switch is not a function) to occur differently on two machines?
Is there a specific way the signAndSend or signTransaction should be implemented when interacting with Stellar Wallet Kit?
Could the issue be related to environment-specific dependencies or differences in how the SDK is resolving the xdr object?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

